# Is there any way to get the number of FB users on a specific country?

Tags: php, facebook, api

I would like to know if is there any possible way to show the total number of users of a specific country in my webpage. As far as I found, you can not get it through API.

Comment: I suspect not, on the basis that a web search of "facebook users by country" returns a number of search results using the word "estimate". That said, [these figures](http://www.socialbakers.com/facebook-statistics/) look quite accurate (though they aren't referenced, afaict).

Comment: No official APIs, but there are "hacky" ways to do this. Look into the marketing tool of Facebook.

Comment: @Mahn Can you point me to one that does what I want to achieve ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos see the answer I just wrote; as far as I know this is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you really want the total number of users on facebook who have 'liked' or used facebooks oauth to connected with your site.

Do you use graph api in your site?  I'm pretty sure you can query by country name--as long as the user's who have shared that info with you have provided it.

Check this out... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

And this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

From their site

> Facebook Insights provides the ability to see geographic and
>   demographic data for people that have Liked a Page or installed an
>   app. Location data is based on the geographic location of each person
>   as determined by their browser IP address and is limited to the top 20
>   countries and cities. All other demographic information is aggregated
>   and non-personally identifiable.

Generic searches can be done like this: 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&place=166793820034304

Where the place id is the id for whatever you want to search on.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&place=166793820034304

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I need the total number of members of a specific country or the total number of facebook users.

Comment: Through the "Graph Api Explorer" I tried your suggestion, however I do not get any result. I have also replaced the place with the ID of where I live.

Comment: I see... You want general demographic info for all of facebook, not just people connected with your site. N

Answer (score 1):

**Disclamer: This method is not supported by Facebook. Use it at your own risk. I take no responsibility whatsoever.**

1. Go to: https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/adscreator/
2. Fill in the ad info with something random (eg. google.com as the url)
3. In the next part you'll notice a dynamic reach estimation that changes depending on the parameters you select, including country. Try changing the country and observe the network activity with for instance the developers tools of Google Chrome.
4. Call the ajax url that returns the json data with the proper parameters programatically, this should be easy to figure out in the previous step.
5. Collect and store the json data for your evil deeds.
6. ???
7. PROFIT!

The actual ajax call and parameters change from time to time, which is why I didn't include them directly, but it should be easy enough to figure it all out. Also note that they are *estimates*, even if they come from Facebook, they don't count every single user every time an advertiser sets up an ad — it's the best estimate you can possibly get though.

This method as I mentioned is neither official nor supported by Facebook, but sites like socialbakers.com or checkfacebook.com have been using them for ages. (There, I revealed the secret)